# Best practice for ensuring rails scaffold saves empty form fields as nil rather than empty string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scaffolding

When creating a rails scaffold, the scaffold will save an empty form field as `""`.

I realise this will cause some complications in some places down the track as an application grows.

What's the best practice way of ensuring for fields blank when submitted are saved as `nil` rather than `""` ?

Comment: It's a little long in the tooth, but this gem https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer lets you convert empty attributes to nils.

Comment: @dbugger Why do you recommend a gem that is 3 major versions of rails behind and hasn't been maintained since 2015 for a very simple problem like this? Just overwrite the setter to `super(value.presence)` where you want this to happen. Sometimes you don't want to overwrite it, because `nil` and `''` can convey differing information. `''` means user chose to leave it empty where `nil` stands for that no decision has been made yet, user hasn't submitted the form

Comment: @SiimLiiser my inexperience probably isn't helping here. I wonder if saving `""` as `nil` is even best practice (e.g. since as you say the "" may have been intended by the user, and may have a different meaning to `nil` depending on the use case). I am curious to know what most applications do, as this must be quite common? (I just happened to notice it because things started appearing in the view that shouldn't have been there, since the view used `if !@thing.nil?` (when it should have been `if @thing.present?`). But other problems could emerge as well. Curious to know what is recommend.

Comment: @SiimLiiser because it works at volume declaratively configuring which attributes to normalize. I personally don't want to maintain overwriting setters in 200+ models.  If nothing else it is an example of what can be done.

Comment: Can't you just set `nil` as the default value in the migrations?  Maybe I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @RockwellRice `nil` is the default anyway. The problem is when a user updates some fields, all the ones that are left untouched change from `nil` to `""` (I guess, technically, an empty string is submitted via params and hence those values get changed from `nil` to `""`